# Automated scripting changes to a CAD file

Tags: scripting, autocad, dwg

I am working as part of a project using a piece of third part software that promised, among its other features, to export items to AutoCAD format. Unfortunately it hasn't lived up to its promise and I have been tasked to create a script which will process a list of items and automatically add elements to an AutoCAD file at the model-space coordinates listed in the item list. These elements are:

Dashed and full lines of greater than unary thickness.
Various symbols which have been provided to us in DWG format.

Unfortunately I have no idea where to start. I'm looking for advice on how to find the quickest, simplest way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relatively easy undertaking in AutoLisp. From AutoLisp you can call normal commands (such as INSERT) and pass variables (such as block/dwg file names, coordinates etc...) as the parameters with ease.

Here is a great starting place to learn:

http://www.afralisp.net/autolisp/tutorials/index.php?category_id=1

and here is the best place to ask questions and search for snippets:

http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Visual-LISP-AutoLISP-and-General/bd-p/130

Comment: Thanks, I've had a look at this already and been non-plussed by a few difficulties, not having good access to autocad being one of them. Right now I'm actually considering the DWF toolkit as a more reliable, if complicated, way of getting things done.